# Facebook login disable automatic redirection

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using facebook login functionality, it works well and the redirection is done automatically when i'm connected on Facebook, but Im trying now to do the redirection only if the user clicks on the button facebook login, here is my code :

Thanks for your help.

Ps: Sorry for my bad english

```
<button id="fb_login_button"
      onclick="FB.login(function(){ /* this is a callback function */ },
      {scope: 'email,user_birthday,read_stream'});
       return false;" class="button button-facelogin" > Via Facebook

</button>



    <script>



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WEBSITE/index.php', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });




  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs.

     top.location = window.location = "REDIRECTION URL"



    if (response.status === 'connected' && $GLOBALS["disconected"]=== "false")  {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.

      testAPI();


    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();



    } else { 
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };



  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split your code in two files :

Index.php

```
<button id="fb_login_button" onclick="location.href='facebookLoginPage.php" class="button button-facelogin" > Via Facebook
</button>
```

facebookLoginPage.php

```
<script>

FB.login(function(){ /* this is a callback function */ },{scope: 'email,user_birthday,read_stream'});

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WEBSITE/index.php', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  top.location = window.location = "REDIRECTION URL"
    if (response.status === 'connected' && $GLOBALS["disconected"]=== "false")  {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else { 
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I did, but nothing happens when I'm on facebookLoginPage.php 

you can check  www.storyser.com/2/demo-login.html 

thanks